# Sharepoint 2010 Content types Hyperlinks and Word QuickParts

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2010, content-type

Sharepoint 2010
I'm slowly making progress with Sharepoint, but have encountered a problem with Content Types and Word Quickparts.
What I'm trying to do:
I want a Content type to hold summary information for manuals and related documents that might be located in separate libraries. I want to display this information in a Table within Word (by setting up a template) using Word Quick Parts>Document property fields.
This table would then summarise all the relevant fields and their related links at the top of a document that in turn summarises information about a particular system.This Word document in turn would be stored in a separate document library.
This all works fine for dates, text descriptions, check boxes, yes/no fields and drop down selections as I can find the related Word Quick Parts>Document Property
[image: Content type snippet]

However, the "Hyperlink or Picture" Type fields are not present in the Word Quick Parts>Document Property fields.
 
So
Am I completely misunderstanding what content types are for? 
or
Is there a setting within sharepoint that would make these hyperlinks visible in the Word Quick Parts?
or
 Is there a better alternate solution.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperlink is not available as property in Word Quick Parts.

Sadly, you can access to this field in Word when you click in the property icon. This will display all the SharePoint property of the document with the hyperlink field.

A workaround would be to create a simple text field and to put the URL of the hyperlink field in this field. (With Workflow or Event Receiver)

An another deep solution is proposed in this link :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7619237-baa1-4669-af65-0f0a39223aad/sharepoint-metadata-and-office-quickparts-hyperlinks-are-not-appearing-in-the-quick-part-list?forum=worddev

This is about create two properties, one for the text, one for the url. Then to arrange it in Word in order to get an hyperlink.

Since Microsoft seems to be removing a lot of its legacy web pages, the content of the above link is copied below:

> a. In the sharepoint list, you will need two text properties, one for
>   the link text and one for the display text. Let's call them hllink1
>   and hldisplay1. For a sample document, put some text in each of these
>   properties.
>
> b. in the template,
>
> - insert the hllink1 Document Property and the hldisplay1 Document Property. This is a temporary move that will let you change thevalues
>     of these properties without displaying the DIP
>
>   - insert a HYPERLINK field as follows
>
>     - use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of field code braces { }
>     - type HYPERLINK "" between the {}, so you have
>
> { HYPERLINK "" }
>
> then insert another copy of the hllink1 Document Property between the ""
>
> { HYPERLINK "the Document Property for hllink1" }
>
> c. select the Hyperlink field and use F9 to update it. When you show
>   the result (Alt-F9), you should see a clickable hyperlink where the
>   "display text" is the same as the link text
>
> d. Click somewhere inside the display text, and insert the hldisplay1
>   Document Property.
>
> e. Carefully select the remainder of the display text and delete it.
>   You should stil be left with a hyperlink that can be ctrl-clicked in
>   the usual way.
>
> f. Modify the texts in hllink1 and hldisplay1. However notice that,
>   as a maximum, the hyperlink display text will update automatically.
>   The tooltip for the hyperlink does not update automatically.
>
> g. Select the hyperlink and press F9 to update it. The tooltip/link
>   text should update